# Laravel 5.1 seems not to use the document root setted on nginx

Tags: php, redirect, nginx, laravel-5, routes

Four days now, I'm trying to make a laravel 5.1 app to work in a subdir with nginx. By starting from zero i have some progress but i'm stucked now because laravel seems not to understand that it belongs to a subfolder and every route except the '/' doesn't work as expected.

I'm trying to understand if this occurs because a missconfiguration on nginx conf rewrite rule or something in laravel.

First of all that's my directory tree:

```
/srv/http --> Web servers' root
/srv/http/finics --> Laravel's public folder (is a symlink to /srv/laravel/public)
```

Here is the respective config at nginx for the /finics location.

```
location  /finics/ {
    root /srv/http/;


try_files $uri $uri/ @laravel;

    location ~ \.php(?:$|/) {
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
      fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
      fastcgi_param modHeadersAvailable true; #Avoid sending the security headers twice
      fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    }

}


location @laravel {
    rewrite /finics/(.*)$ /finics/index.php?/$1 last;
}

location ~ \.css$ {}
location ~ \.js$ {}

}
```

For rewriting rule and try_files, i have already tried everything suggested on this site and also in other forums like digital ocean.

Some of them are

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
try_files $uri $uri/ /finics/index.php?$query_string;
rewrite ^/finics/(.*)$ /finics/index.php$query_string; 
try_files $uri $uri/ /finics/index.php$is_args$args;
```

but none of them actually worked.

So the problem, as i said before is that only the / (domain.net/finics/) route is working. If I i click on a app's menu link to transfer me to the accessions it will redirect me to domain.net/accessions and not in domain.net/finics/accessions. That's why i wrote that is seems laravel doesn't understand in which document root belongs. The same thing of course is happening and with all POST requests.

Something saying me that the solution might be easy but i don't know what else to think.

If there is any idea on why this is happening and maybe a hint to fix it i will be very thankful.

Comment: How do you build the links?

Comment: What exactly do you mean ? My routes  or the href values?

Comment: The template where the links are created

Comment: ```<li><a href="/accessions"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> Accession list <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt pull-right"></span></a></li>```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to let Laravel create the URL for you, a link to `/accessions` will just do exactly what you're seeing at the moment, strip the complete path and use *just*  `/accessions` and not any subpath you're in.

```
<a href="{{ url('/accessions') }}">
```

`url` is a helper-function which creates the correct URL for you, see [Basic Routing -> Generating URLs To Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#basic-routing)